# Parsing html data with nutch 1.0 and a custom plugin

Tags: html-parsing, nutch

I am currently trying to write a custom plugin for nutch 1.0. This plugin is supposed to parse html data and filter out relevant information from documents. I have a basic plugin working, it extends the HtmlParserResult object and is executed each time I do a parse.

My problems are two faced at the moment:

1. I do not understand the workflow/pipline of the nutch parsing good enough. I do not find the information about this on the nutch site.
2. I do not understand how the DOM parsing is done, I see that Nutch have set of DOM objects and that the HtmlParser plugin does some DOM parsing, still I have not figured out how this is best done.

Answer (score 1):

I remember making a nutch HTML parsing plugin for a past work. I don't have access to how I did it exactly, but here are the basic points. We wanted to do the following:

1. parse an HTML page but conditionally use a H1 tag or a tag with a certain class as the page title rather than the actual //html/head/title
2. There were some special pieces of data that were sometimes on the page (ie what tab was selected, which would tell us if this was a retail customer, a bank customer, or a corporate customer).
3. etc.

What I did was just find the html-parse plugin class (I'm having trouble finding the actual class name), and extend it. Then override the parsing function. The new function should call the `super` function and then can walk the DOM tree to find the special data you are looking for. In my case I'd look for a better title and then override the value that the `super` function came up with.

For your second question, I'm not clear what you are asking about. I think you are asking what happens when the DOM isn't well formed? I would just dig through the nutch code (http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.nutch/nutch/1.3/) and find out how the parsing is done (i'm sure they use a library to do it). That should tell you more about if things are greedy, or what.

Holler if you have questions.